# XPages: ask a confirmation when saving and set a value if confirmed

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a document that gets published using an xagent (that does all sorts of things to the document).

Before sending to the xagent, I would like to ask the user if he wants the effective date of the document to be set to today's date.  For now, I don't have that field available in edit mode on the page, but I guess I'll need it.

The big question is how to ask a confirmation (do you want the date to be set to today?) and put the date in the field before actually saving the document and sending it to the xagent page.  I already have some simple actions into that save button.  Here is the code:

```
<xp:button value="Save and Publish" id="button6">
    <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:database.queryAccessRoles(session.getEffectiveUserName()).contains('[Admin]') && currentDocument.isEditable()}]]></xp:this.rendered>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:actionGroup>
                <xp:modifyField name="Status" var="pageDocument">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(getComponent("publishLater1").getValue() == "1") {
        return "Scheduled Publication";
    } else {
        return "To Be Published";
    }}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:modifyField>
                <xp:saveDocument var="pageDocument">
                </xp:saveDocument>
                <xp:executeScript>
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:  //remove the lock doc
    //unlockDoc(pageDocument.getDocument().getUniversalID());

    //for scheduled publications, a LotusScript agent will do the work
    var res=facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();

    if(getComponent("publishLater1").getValue() == "0") {
        // Now load the publish Agent
        res.sendRedirect(@Left(facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath(),".nsf")+".nsf/xPublish?OpenAgent&docid=" + pageDocument.getDocument().getUniversalID());
    } else {
        //send to the drafts view, to show it has the clock icon in the draft view
        res.sendRedirect(@Left(facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath(),".nsf")+".nsf/adminDrafts.xsp");
    } }]]></xp:this.script>
                </xp:executeScript>
            </xp:actionGroup>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
    <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o pull-left fa-2x">
    </i>
</xp:button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `pageDocument` is a dominoDocument datasource. A dominoDocument datasource is either all read only or all editable. And SSJS has access to that datasource. So add another `executeScript` action and you can modify whichever other field you want to as well.

What I'd recommend, though, is to skip the simple actions and do everything in script. The SSJS editor allows you to see all the methods available for a dominoDocument datasource. With a little knowledge of LotusScript or a little investigation, it should be obvious which method to use to replace an item value for the "Modify Field" simple action (quick tip, again go to the datasource rather than the `publishLater1` component) and which method to save the document. If you start breaking away from simple actions and building your confidence in SSJS, it will give you greater flexibility in the long run.

Comment: thanks Paul, but if I change to SSJS, how do I get the user's input before doing the save and the redirect?  That is whereI get stuck...  I am fine with the SSJS code instead of simple actions.  I have seen some posts on the subject, but the client side code is triggered onComplete, after the SSJS code has ran, so it doesn't really work for what I want to do...  Can I add client side code in an ExecuteScript tag???

Comment: Any event handler can run CSJS before SSJS, just use the Client tab. If the CSJS code returns true, the refresh happens and the SSJS runs; if not, the refresh isn't triggered. (Apologies if you were aware of that!) Does this cover what you need? Just remember any computed SSJS in the CSJS is calculated and the output passed to the browser so, e.g., you could not use SSJS to get another component's newly-modified value. You would need to get the component's client-side ID and use CSJS to retrieve its value.

Comment: I didn't know the client side Js ran before the SSJS, and that the SSJS code runs depending on the client side's JS return value.  That did it: I used a simple confirm on the client side to ask my question!  Thank you both for your time   :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do it several ways I'd think.  If you're using the extension library you could use a dialogBox.  so your save and publish button opens a dialog box with your question or even additional fields.  Then you add a cancel button of course to the dialog box but also a "continue" button.  That button accesses the fields if you put any in or knows that they want "today's" date and then that button calls the xagent passing in any appropriate parameters.